# JavaFX dropshadow at the bottom

Tags: java, css, javafx, shadow, dropshadow

I have a question, is it possible to create a drop-shadow only at the bottom of a button?
I am using this piece of code at the moment, but this is at 2 sides.

```
-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, #993300, 3, 10, 2, 3);
```

Thank you very much already.

Comment: Since Mr. GenericJon decided to delete my answer, I'll have to post a commment. Reduce x offset and maybe the radius if you don't want the shadow to overlap: `dropshadow(three-pass-box, #993300, 0, 1.0, 0, 3);`